# Too many columns in query, MySQL Error Code: 1117

Tags: mysql, hibernate

I very recently started the process of trying to get a undocumented and poorly designed project under control. After struggling to get the thing built locally, I started running into errors when going through various functionalities.

Most of these problems appear to be a result of MySQL errors due to the way my product is generating Hibernate criteria queries. For example, when doing an autocomplete on the displayName of an object, the criteria query that results from this action is very large. I end up with around 2200 fields to select from around 50 tables. When hibernate attempts to execute this query I get an error:

```
30-Mar-2018 11:43:07.353 WARNING [http-nio-8080-exec-8] org.hibernate.util.JDBCExceptionReporter.logExceptions SQL Error: 1117, SQLState: HY000
30-Mar-2018 11:43:07.353 SEVERE [http-nio-8080-exec-8] org.hibernate.util.JDBCExceptionReporter.logExceptions Too many columns
[ERROR] 11:43:07 pos.services.HorriblyDefinedObjectAjax - could not execute query
org.hibernate.exception.GenericJDBCException: could not execute query
```

I turned on general logging for MySQL and obtained the criteria query that is trying to be executed. If I attempt to execute it in MySQLWorkbench I also get the following result:

```
Error Code: 1117. Too many columns
```

I've gone to the QA instances of this application and the autocompletes work there, which seems to indicate there is a way that this huge query will execute. Is it possible that I just do not have the right MySQL configurations on?

Currently my `sql_mode='NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION'`, is there anything else I might need to do?

Comment: Sounds like bad programming, we are going to need to see code to be able to help you.

Comment: Bummer, I can say with no hubris that this is bad programming. I am not going to waste your time any further then, I was hoping maybe there was just setting for MySQL that would make this work. But my job is to refactor and redesign, so I guess I found my starting point.

Comment: You can post some SQL and we would be glad to help. How nay columns out of the 2200 are really used. That is a lot of unnecessary network and server traffic. If it is select *, begin by limiting to just the fields that you need.

Comment: @Chuck Hey! I figured it out, turns out I had just installed MySql 5.7.21, but the application in production was using MySql 5.6.39. After I downgraded the huge select statements Hibernate was generating started working. I uhh... don't know what changed between the two versions. But, either way, the methods have no excuse for making hibernate get his much information. I'll need to refactor this for certain. Thanks again for taking time to check this post :)

Comment: Great, glad that you got it working again.